# "incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable" for LinkedList

Tags: java, deque

I got an error of `incompatible type: cannot infer type-variable(s) E (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)` from the 2nd statement of the following code,

```
Deque<TreeNode>[] stacks = new Deque[2];
Arrays.set(stacks, LinkedList::new);
```

However, substitute LinkedList with ArrayDeque fixes the error,

```
Arrays.set(stacks, ArrayDeque::new);
```

Both `LinkedList` and `ArrayDeque` implement the `Deque` interface. I am confused why it works for `ArrayDeque` but not for `LinkedList`?

Comment: Where does this `Arrays` class come from?

Comment: @michalk JDK 1.2 :) (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: @SimonKocurek this class does not have `set` method.

Comment: @michalk my bad. It does have `setAll` method with same signature. Not sure if the implementation is the same though. :/

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek I guess you mean Java 12 (Java 1.2 is essentialy Java 2) and [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll(T[],java.util.function.IntFunction)). The version from Java 7 doesn't support functional constructs.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The `Arrays` class is there from java `1.2` (the "essentialy Java 2"). However just like you pointed out the `setAll` method was not there at the time. But rather came with Java 8.

Comment: Yeah, thats right, setAll is implemented after Java 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in their constructors that you pass:

```java
public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c);
public LinkedList();
```

```java
public ArrayDeque(int numElements);
```

After expanding you get:

```java
Arrays.setAll(stacks, index -> new LinkedList<TreeNode>(index));
```

```java
Arrays.setAll(stacks, index -> new ArrayDeque<>(index));
```

Where `LinkedList` does not have constructor taking `int index`.
To fix your issue just write (the `index` is index in your array):

```java
Arrays.setAll(stacks, index -> new LinkedList<TreeNode>());
```